# Create vector layer/virtual layer with dynamic number of features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector, atlas, virtual-layer

### The problem

I want to create a vector layer in QGIS 3.26 with a varying number of features. The number of features should be the same as the number of raster layers open in the project. So if I have 12 raster layers, I want a point layer with 12 features; if 30 rasters are open in the project, I want to get a layer with 30 points and so on.

*Hint (see at the bottom): I need this as coverage layer for an atlas that outputs each raster layer separately.*

### What I tried

1. I created a point layer called `count_layer` with one feature and a virtual field named `no_of_rasters` with an expression based on the variable `@layers` that returns the number of raster layers opened in the project.
2. The idea now is to create a virtual layer with the query `select make_point (47,15)`.

### The question

Up to this point, everything works. I am now stuck as to how to create not **one** point at coordinates `(47,15)`, but several points - the number of points should correspond to the number created above in step 1: the value in the field `no_of_rasters`.

How to do that?

---

### Context (not necessary to understand the question)

Just to make clear why I want to do that: I want to use the virtual layer as coverage layer for an atlas. I want to output each raster separately, so in the virtual layer, I want to create a virtual field containing for each feature one of the names of the raster layers (using `@layers` and selecting from the resulting array one element corresponding to `@row_number`).

This field (name of raster layer) can than be used in the atlas in the `Lock layers` setting to just output one raster layer per feature of the coverage layer so that in the end, I have an output with each raster layer separately printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want each of the points to have an identical geometry, you could use a recursive CTE and generate a row (with unique id) for each layer as such:

```sql
WITH seq AS (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq 
WHERE n + 1 <= (SELECT no_of_rasters FROM count_layer))

SELECT n, make_point(47,15) AS geometry FROM seq
```

As for assigning a raster name to each generated point, to my knowledge you can't do that in Virtual Layers, but you could set up a virtual field on the virtual layer with the following expression (where `n` is the sequence generated in the virtual layer):

```
array_get(
         array_foreach(
                       array_filter(@layers,
                                    layer_property(@element,'type') =  'Raster'),
                       layer_property(@element,'name')
         ),"n"-1)
```

This just extracts the raster name from the position in the `@layers` array corresponding to `n` - 1 (because zero-index).

Example:

[image]